# 3 column table on a desktop browser to 1 column on a mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, desktop

I've currently got a 3-column table, which shows quite well in a desktop browser - until the cell text becomes a little too long or the browser window is too narrow. That's when it starts looking a little weird. This is currently what I'm using:

CSS:

```css
/* Start tour stats 3 column box */
.tour-stats {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box; border-left: 1px dotted #ccc;
    border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;
    background: #daeaf2;
}
.tour-stats .stat {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    box-sizing: border-box; padding-left: 50px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc; border-right: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.tour-stats .stat.distance {
    background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/distance.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
.tour-stats .stat.start {
    background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/startflag.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
.tour-stats .stat.stop {
    background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/stop.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
.tour-stats .stat.time {
    background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/time.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
    background-size: 23px 23px;
}
.tour-stats .stat.avg-speed {
    background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/avgspeed.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
.tour-stats .stat.tot-distance {
    background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/totaldistance.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tour-stats">
    <div class="stat start">Corowa (08:12)</div>                    
    <div class="stat distance">128.21 km</div>                  
    <div class="stat avg-speed">20.6</div>
    
    <div class="stat stop">Shepparton (16:38)</div>                 
    <div class="stat time">6:13:57</div>
    <div class="stat tot-distance">573.40 km*</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be useful!
Stephen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go...

This might be a little bit advanced for you, but I suggest you to start learning [Bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/). It's very easy to make responsive HTML using Bootstrap’s [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) system.

See the snippet below.

```css
/* Start tour stats 3 column box */

.tour-stats {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #daeaf2;
}

.tour-stats .stat {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.col-md-4 {
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

.tour-stats .stat.distance {
  background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/distance.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}

.tour-stats .stat.start {
  background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/startflag.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}

.tour-stats .stat.stop {
  background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/stop.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}

.tour-stats .stat.time {
  background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/time.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
  background-size: 23px 23px;
}

.tour-stats .stat.avg-speed {
  background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/avgspeed.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}

.tour-stats .stat.tot-distance {
  background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/totaldistance.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="row m-0 tour-stats">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="stat start">Corowa (08:12)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="stat distance">128.21 km</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="stat avg-speed">20.6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row m-0 tour-stats">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="stat stop">Shepparton (16:38)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="stat time">6:13:57</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="stat tot-distance">573.40 km*</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like this one worked! Thanks Cervus!

Comment: One odd thing, though. It's resulted in the links being underlined on that page.

Comment: Try to add `a {text-decoration: none !important}` to your CSS. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I already tried something and solved it.. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways, but in your existing example you can just add a media query where you reset the floats and set the width to 100% for your "cells", like this:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
.tour-stats .stat {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Note: I used 800px max-width here to immediately show the result in the snippet window here. But usually you'd use a smaller value , like 600px.

```css
/* Start tour stats 3 column box */
.tour-stats {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box; border-left: 1px dotted #ccc;
    border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;
    background: #daeaf2;
}
.tour-stats .stat {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    box-sizing: border-box; padding-left: 50px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc; border-right: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.tour-stats .stat.distance {
    background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/distance.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
.tour-stats .stat.start {
    background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/startflag.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
.tour-stats .stat.stop {
    background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/stop.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
.tour-stats .stat.time {
    background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/time.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
    background-size: 23px 23px;
}
.tour-stats .stat.avg-speed {
    background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/avgspeed.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
.tour-stats .stat.tot-distance {
    background: url('https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/totaldistance.png') no-repeat 15px center transparent;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
.tour-stats .stat {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="tour-stats">
    <div class="stat start">Corowa (08:12)</div>                    
    <div class="stat distance">128.21 km</div>                  
    <div class="stat avg-speed">20.6</div>
    
    <div class="stat stop">Shepparton (16:38)</div>                 
    <div class="stat time">6:13:57</div>
    <div class="stat tot-distance">573.40 km*</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes. I tried it, but didn't seem to make any difference. I'm going to try Cervus' Bootstrap example, too. But I'll wait until tomorrow. Not a good idea trying to do that at nearly midnight!

Answer (score 1):

You can use media query on your css file and set the width depend on the screen size with 100%. Example :

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  div {`width: 100%};`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `width` depending on the screen size using media queries ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media))

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  float:left;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  div {
    width:calc(100% / 3);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* defining CSS custom properties on the :root element: */
:root {
  --bgColor: #daeaf2;
  --columns: 3;
  --borderWidth: 1px;
  --borderStyle: dotted;
  --borderColor: #ccc;
  --border: var(--borderWidth) var(--borderStyle) var(--borderColor);
}

/* specifying 'box-sizing' (as well as the other properties) on
   all elements in the document, instead of repeating the declaration
   on each element in turn: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* serve only as a wrapper element around the various .tour-stats
   elements: */
main {
  /* using CSS logical properties to set the margin on the block
     -axis (top/bottom in English languages): */
  margin-block: 1em;
  /* setting the margin on the inline-axis (left/right) in
     English languages: */
  margin-inline: auto;
  /* defining the width of the element using clamp(), so that
     it has a width of 80 viewport-units, unless that is less
     than 500px in which case it will take 500px and with an
     upper limit of 1200px: */
  width: clamp(500px, 80vw, 1200px);
}

/* styling the ::before pseudo-element of all elements with
   a 'data-approach' attribute (the labelling I added):*/
[data-approach]::before {
  /* assigning the --bgColor CSS property as the background
     -color to the pseudo-element(s): */
  background-color: var(--bgColor);
  /* setting the value of the 'data-approach' attribute,
     concatenated with the ':' character as the text
     -content of the pseudo-element: */
  content: attr(data-approach) ':';
  /* positioning the element with reference to its closest
     ancestor with a non-static position property-value:*/
  position: absolute;
  /* CSS logical property to set padding on the element's
     inline axis: */
  padding-inline: 0.5em;
  /* moving the element towards the beginning of the element,
     to position it outside of the left edge of the ancestor:*/
  right: 100%;
  /* moving the pseudo-element up, multiplying the size of the
     --borderWidth custom property by -1 (negative numbers
     move the element vertically 'up', and positive numbers
     vertically 'down'): */
  top: calc(-1 * var(--borderWidth));
}

/* Start tour stats 3 column box */
.tour-stats {
  /* setting a 24px margin at the end of the element's
     block axis: */
  margin-block-end: 24px;
  /* CSS logical properties to place borders on the
     inline-start (left, in English) and block-start
     (top, in English) edges of the element: */
  border-inline-start: var(--border);
  border-block-start: var(--border);
  /* setting the background-color to the value of the
     --bgColor custom proerty: */
  background-color: var(--bgColor);
  /* to position the labelling that I've added: */
  position: relative;
}

.tour-stats .stat {
  /* defining a custom property on all elements matching
     the selector; this sets the --imgURI property as the
     background-image of the element: */
  --bg: var(--imgURI) no-repeat 15px center transparent;
  /* we then use that rule immediately: */
  background: var(--bg);
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-inline-start: 50px;
  padding-block: 12px;
  border-block-end: var(--border);
  border-inline-end: var(--border);
}

 .stat.distance {
  /* in each of the .stat elements; the benefit of this is that the background
     rule is defined on all elements; and the specific image URI is defined
     only on the element that uses it. It's just a little DRY-er than repeating
     the whole declaration on each element: */
  --imgURI: url(https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/distance.png);
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}

 .stat.start {
  --imgURI: url(https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/startflag.png);
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}

.stat.stop {
  --imgURI: url(https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/stop.png);
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}

.stat.time {
  --imgURI: url(https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/time.png);
  background-size: 23px 23px;
}

.tour-stats .stat.avg-speed {
  --imgURI: url(https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/avgspeed.png);
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}

.stat.tot-distance {
  --imgURI: url(https://www.rtw.bike/wp-content/icons/tour-stats/totaldistance.png);
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}

/* CSS float layout: */

/* this defines a pseudo element which will take the full width of its parent and
   clear all floats within that parent which then forces the parent to wrap its
   descendants: */
.tour-stats.float::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

.tour-stats.float .stat {
  float: left;
  /* defining the width of the floated elements by dividing the 100% parent-width
     by the number of desired columns, as defined in the --columns custom property: */
  width: calc(100% / var(--columns));
}

/* CSS flex-box layout: */
.tour-stats.flex {
  display: flex;
  /* specifies that the flex-direction is 'row', and that the elements will
     wrap to a new line if required: */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.tour-stats.flex .stat {
  /* defining the flex-basis of the elements as above, dividing 100% (parent's width)
     by the number of desired 'columns': */
  flex-basis: calc(100% /var(--columns));
  /* flex-grow 1 allows the elements to expand to fill the available space in the
     row they're in: */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

/* CSS grid layout: */
.tour-stats.grid {
  display: grid;
  /* defining the required number of columns held in the --columns custom property,
     and each column will take one fraction of the available space: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
}

/* when the screen size is 700px or less we update some properties to change the layout: */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  :root {
    /* we reduce the column-count to 1 as required: */
    --columns: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="tour-stats float" data-approach="float">
    <div class="stat start">Corowa (08:12)</div>
    <div class="stat distance">128.21 km</div>
    <div class="stat avg-speed">20.6</div>

    <div class="stat stop">Shepparton (16:38)</div>
    <div class="stat time">6:13:57</div>
    <div class="stat tot-distance">573.40 km*</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tour-stats flex" data-approach="flex">
    <div class="stat start">Corowa (08:12)</div>
    <div class="stat distance">128.21 km</div>
    <div class="stat avg-speed">20.6</div>

    <div class="stat stop">Shepparton (16:38)</div>
    <div class="stat time">6:13:57</div>
    <div class="stat tot-distance">573.40 km*</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tour-stats grid" data-approach="grid">
    <div class="stat start">Corowa (08:12)</div>
    <div class="stat distance">128.21 km</div>
    <div class="stat avg-speed">20.6</div>

    <div class="stat stop">Shepparton (16:38)</div>
    <div class="stat time">6:13:57</div>
    <div class="stat tot-distance">573.40 km*</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3tmbgwez/)

References:

- [`[attribute]` selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).
- [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attr).
- [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).
- [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).
- [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).
- [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp).
- [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear).
- [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).
- [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).
- [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).
- [`flex-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow).
- [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow).
- [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)
- [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
- [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`padding-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
- [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
- [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).
- [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).
- [`right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right).
- [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top).
- [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).
- [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).

Bibliography:

- "[A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)," CSS-Tricks.com.
- "[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)," CSS-Tricks.com.
- "[Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)," Mozilla Developer Network.
- "[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)," Mozilla Developer Network.